Nuance of ならいいのに here
Revy (probably) has doubts about an upcoming opponent who is said to be strong like a cyborg:

坊主その姉ちゃんがお前が信じてるほどに ―
強い奴ならいいのにとあたしも願うよ
持て余してんだこちとら
最近このカトラスをな
Kid. I really hope...
...that the woman you talk about is as strong as you believe.
This hasn't seen much action lately.
This Cutlass. [show's translation]

Conditional plus いいのに usually is used in a counter-factual situation, where the wish does not match the result.
But even though Revy is clearly expressing doubt about the strength of this opponent, because she is literally wishing [願う] for a strong opponent, and their fight is in the future, I wonder what meaning のに even takes.
From what I understand from this question, this sentence can mean:
「君も来ればいいのに。」
"You should come also~~ (but you haven't done so/will not)"
I imagine here the person in question has in some way indicated that they won't come. But in this episode Revy has no indication that her opponent will easily lose besides that fact that Revy herself is very arrogant.
My question is: what does のに express here in a non-counterfactual situation?
In my eyes, there is nothing yet to "lament" about the strength of her opponent.

ならいいのに can be used with something that is very unlikely to happen in the future. In other words, it doesn't have to be 100% impossible. This のに indicates the speaker's strong doubts about the strength of the opponent.

強い奴ならいいな
I hope she is strong.
強い奴ならいいのにな
If only she is strong.

The former is a simple hope, while the latter is a mix of hope and strong doubts.
